# embed a web browser within a java web application?

Tags: jakarta-ee, browser, cross-platform

What is the best approach to put some web browser  on IFrame in JAVA web application?
I have searche a lot and I found javaFX webview. But the problem that it display  as a pop up.

Comment: A WebView displayed in a JFrame doesn't need to display as a pop-up.  Perhaps add an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows what you are doing that generates the pop-up.

Comment: I'm working on j2ee web application not in desktop application. So I can't work with JFrame.

Comment: Why can't you just display the web-page in the iframe, it is already inside a web-browser.

Comment: Because i can't execute navigation timing api in web-page through iframe. I'm working on web application that tests speed web performance using selenium.